# When i am trying to run php artisan tinker command its show me exception in laravel php artisan

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

When I am trying to run this command it shows me this exception

> [ErrorException]  Declaration of Psy\Shell::renderException() should be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Application::renderException(Exception $e, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output).

How to solve?

Comment: does adding "prefer-stable": true to composer.json help?

Comment: When you set your project up, did you happen to use the 'develop' version? i.e `composer create-project laravel/laravel xxx-dev develop`